# How can I show the structure of a python list with its datatypes and without showing the value of the data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python list which is coming from an API response where values are base64 encoded images, so the strings are super long.  I want to show the structure and data types of the list without showing the values.

```
{
...
"api_response": [
  [
    [
      "super long string of base64 encoded image",
      "super long string of base64 encoded image",
      "super long string of base64 encoded image",
      "super long string of base64 encoded image",
    ]
  ]
]
}
```

When i try:

```
print(type(api_response))
```

The result is:

```
<class 'list'>
```

When I try:

```
print(api_response)
```

I get a giant blob of text which shows the base64 string.  I want formatted and linted like:

```
[
  [
    [
      <string>,
      <string>,
      <string>,
      <string>,
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: The data is always in a certain location. Do you have an example of a list comprehension?

Answer (score 2):

A list in python can hold data of multiple different datatypes.

You could use `map` and `type` on your list to get all datatypes like this:

```
l = ["a", 1, True]
list(map(type, l))
# [<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'bool'>]
```

Comment: you need recursive function to use it on OP example object, given object["api_response"] ---> list(map(type, object["api_response"] ) outputs [<class 'list'>]

Comment: actually: map() function returns a map object(which is an iterator) of the results after applying the given function to each item of a given iterable (list, tuple etc.), so you'll get a list of class string repeted for the  length of the OP object innermost string

Comment: Yes, they are all strings so it is correct. I've just modified the input data to better show how it works :)

Answer (score 2):

If your data objects are at various depth within you list,

e.g.

```
l = [[["aa", "bb", 345], "cc"]]
```

I would do a recursive function like so:

```
def type_map(l):
    if not isinstance(l, list):
        return str(type(l))
    else:
        l = [type_map(x) for x in l]
    return l


print(type_map(l))
```

outputs:

```
[[["<class 'str'>", "<class 'str'>", "<class 'int'>"], "<class 'str'>"]]
```

Then for pretty printing, I would use json formatter of `json` module

```
import json
print (json.dumps(type_map(l), indent=2))
```

outputs:

```
[
  [
    [
      "<class 'str'>",
      "<class 'str'>",
      "<class 'int'>"
    ],
    "<class 'str'>"
  ]
]
```